# remix compiler warning infinite gas requirement

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, gas, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm trying to deploy a trivial faucet program which compiles OK with remix but I get the following error.
"Gas requirement of function Faucet.withdraw(uint256) high: infinite. "
This means that while it compiles I cannot deploy it to my Ganache blockchain.
I understand the concept of gas for a function but I cannot see what is potentially infinite here: I have put a tiny limit on any withdrawal amount.

Could someone please explain?

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

contract Faucet {

    function withdraw(uint256 withdraw_amount) public   {    
        require(withdraw_amount <= 2000000);
        msg.sender.transfer(withdraw_amount);
        }

    // Accept any incoming amount
    function () external payable {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Gas requirement of function Faucet.withdraw(uint256) high: infinite.

Thisis a misleading warning caused by the `require()`. It can be safely ignored.

> This means that while it compiles I cannot deploy it to my Ganache blockchain

Not true. You can deploy it.

> pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

*In my opinion*, this is bad form except in librarys and inheritable contracts. You do indeed have a problem with 0.6.x and above because the fallback syntax is changed from an unnamed function to an explicitly named `fallback()` function.

One cannot know what *breaking changes* will be introduced in the future, so top-level contracts (to deploy) should indicate precisely what compiler to use. One can safely use `^` and `>=` for inherited modules that will not be deployed on their own.

I did not know what you used because it is ambiguous. However, I can see that it compiles and deploys with 0.5.16, and it does not with 0.6.x so ...

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract Faucet {

    function withdraw(uint256 withdraw_amount) public   {    
        require(withdraw_amount <= 2000000);
        msg.sender.transfer(withdraw_amount);
        }

    // Accept any incoming amount
    function () external payable {}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're dead right about the pragma, it's a stupid error. I did comment out the require() but Remix still says the gas supply is infinite; if I comment out msg.sender.transfer line it stops the error but. of course, makes the function useless.

Comment: That sounds like trying to send more money than the contract has.